# Jquery Countdown behaves unexpected

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

Please help me. I am trying to figure out why this countdown is not working...

I am using this Jquery script from this website
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I am using the third example from its callback tab

My code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Countdown</title>
    <link rel="nofollow" type="text/css" href="https://justpaste.it/redirect/1ytp/http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#expireMessage').countdown({
            var shortly

            until: shortly,
            expiryText: '<div class="over">It\'s all over</div>'});

             $('#expireMessageStart').click(function() {
             alert("hi");  
             shortly = new Date();
             shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5);
             $('#expireMessage').countdown('option', {until: shortly});
          });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="expireMessage"></div>
        <span id="expireMessage" class="countdown"></span>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" id="expireMessageStart">Start</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me in running this countdown.

Comment: what does the javaskript console of firebug or chrome say ?

Comment: Your path to jQuery is wrong. `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.jsjquery.min.js`

Comment: I corrected but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Your link to JQuery is wrong. Use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js It gives you the latest version...

Answer (score 0):

Besides fixing your jQuery path as mentioned above, declaring shortly before calling the countdown function might solve your problem

> $(document).ready(function() {
>      var shortly;
>      ...
>   }

Comment: I've set up a jsfiddle for you, please let me know if you'd like it to function differently :)

[jsfiddle.net/akesw/](http://jsfiddle.net/akesw/)

Comment: It seems like the problem was where you placed `var shortly;`